# Node: send data from middlware to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm using express and I need to create some middleware which is for validation and

I’ve something like

**Code**:

```
app.use(‘/upload', fromData)
app.use(‘/upload', function firstUpload(req, res, next) {
    return fileHandler(req, res, next)
        .then((status) => {
            res.statusCode = 201;
            res.end(status)
        }).catch((err) => {
            return next(new appError(500, err));
        });
});
```

Now I use another function fromHandler

```
function formData(req) {

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.multiEntry = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    const filesInfo = Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
        const file = files[key];
        const filePath = file.path;
        const fileExt = path.extname(file.name);
        const fileName = path.basename(file.name, fileExt);
        return {filePath, fileExt};
    });
 }
  Resolve(filesInfo)
}
```

What I need is to return the data `Resolve(filesInfo)` from the formData function to 
The `fileHandler` function, how can I do it? The fileHandler function need to get the `filesInfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a promise here. middleware use `next` function as the `callback` to go to next handler. Before it, you should put data from the middleware into req object. After that, you can use by getting from `req. filesInfo`.

```
function formData(req, res, next) {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.multiEntry = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err || fields.length === 0) {
       res.status(500).json({ message: 'you are done' }); // <- this is where you stop the request with an error.
    }
    const filesInfo = Object.keys(files).map((key) => {
        const file = files[key];
        const filePath = file.path;
        const fileExt = path.extname(file.name);
        const fileName = path.basename(file.name, fileExt);
        return {filePath, fileExt};
    });
    req.filesInfo = filesInfo;
    next();
  }
}

function fileHandler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.filesInfo); /* <- you can also get the filesInfo here */ 
  return Promise.resolve({});
}

app.use(‘/upload', fromData)
app.use(‘/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    // console.log(req.filesInfo); => You can get your filesInfo here and do whatever you want
    return fileHandler(req, res, next)
        .then((status) => {
            res.statusCode = 201;
            res.end(status)
        }).catch((err) => {
            return next(new appError(500, err));
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide please the all context with the fucntions and middlware (like the example I put) ?\

Comment: I add the comment on the code so that you can know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Im closing the question :) , one last question , assume that I want to validate some field which I got in the req that it equal to  something , and if not cancel all the request (like token which I got in the form data) how do i cancel the next to the next function ?

Comment: I mean if `fields.token != "123" ` dont process to the `fileHandler` function ...

Comment: You just need to `if (err) { return res.status(500).json(err) }`. It will break and done. (err or any custom comparision).

Comment: but I dont want to chancel all the program just the request

Comment: Does this will cancel the `next()` ?

Comment: It doesn't cancel the program. It just stop the request with status code error.

Comment: Ok thanks!, so where do you suggest doing this ? any recommendation ? assume this is my program...

Comment: I updated the code so on the answer adding breaking when some validation or error.